# SQL bulk copy : Trigger not getting fired

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database-connection

I am copying data from Table1 to Table2 table using sql bulk copy. I have applied trigger on Table2, but my trigger is not firing on every row. Here is my trigger and sqlbulkcopy function.

```
SqlConnection dstConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Destination"].ConnectionString);
string destination = dstConn.ConnectionString;

//Get data from Source in our case T1 
DataTable dataTable = new Utility().GetTableData("Select * From  [db_sfp_ems].[dbo].[tbl_current_data_new] where [start_date]>'" + calculate_daily_Time + "' and status=0" , source);
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(source, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers)
{
    //Add table name of source
    DestinationTableName = "tbl_current_data",
    BatchSize = 100000,
    BulkCopyTimeout = 360
};
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
//MessageBox.Show("Data Transfer Succesfull.");
dstConn.Close();
```

------Trigger-----

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[tbl_current_data]
   AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN

    declare @intime datetime
    declare @sdp_id numeric
    declare @value numeric(9,2)


    SELECT @intime= DATEADD(SECOND, -DATEPART(SECOND, start_date), start_date)  FROM INSERTED

    SELECT @sdp_id= sdp_id  FROM INSERTED
    SELECT @value= value  FROM INSERTED

    INSERT INTO Table3(sdp_id,value,start_date)
    VALUES
    (
           @sdp_id,@value,@intime
    )
```

Comment: i would have thought the whole point of a bulk copy was to do it as fast as possible and not fire triggers!

Comment: Not very sure, but as bulk copy does not commit it after every row, your trigger will not get activated after every row. But just when bulk copy commits the changes.

Comment: The trigger doesn't not apply in bulk operations, but in atomic ones. You should handle the insertion row by row if you want to make the trigger work

Comment: when i decrease the BatchSize = 100000, to 20,then my triggers are getting fired. But i dont want batch size 20 ,I want minimum batch size 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger is fired after an insert, whether that insert concerns 0, 1 or multiple records makes no difference to the trigger. So, even though you are inserting a whole bunch of records, the trigger is only fired once. This is by design, and not specific for `BULK_INSERT`; this is true for every kind of insert. This also means that the `inserted` pseudo table can hold 0, 1 or multiple records. This is a common pitfall. Be sure to write your trigger in such a way it can handle multiple records. For example: `SELECT @sdp_id= sdp_id  FROM INSERTED` won't work as expected if `inserted` holds multiple records. The variable will be set, but you cannot know what value (from which inserted record) it's going to hold.

This is all part of the set based philosophy of SQL, it is best not to try and break that philosophy by using loops or other RBAR methods. Stay in the set mindset.

Comment: So you mean ,It is impossible to generate trigger while using sqlbulkcopy

Comment: No, it *is* possible to trigger the trigger with bulk insert, that's why you have `SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers`. It is **not** possible to fire the trigger for *every row* in the bulk insert. It's all or nothing. If it's really, *really* required, you can loop through the rows in your `datatable` and fire off individual inserts. I struggle to think of a situation where that would be required though.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is simply broken.  In SQL Server, triggers handle multiple rows at one time.  Assuming that `inserted` has one row is fatal error -- and I wish it caused a syntax error.

I think this is the code you want:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[tbl_current_data]
   AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table3 (sdp_id, value, start_date)
        SELECT sdp_id, value, 
               DATEADD(SECOND, -DATEPART(SECOND, start_date), start_date)
        FROM inserted i;
END;
```

Apart from being correct, another advantage is that the code is simpler to write.

Note:  You are setting the "seconds" part to 0.  However -- depending on the type -- `start_date` could have fractional seconds that remain.  If that is an issue, ask another question.

Comment: I have to check @intime  parameter,thats why i didnt write the trigger as per you suggest.I have to check following condition.                     if (((SELECT datediff(minute, (select top 1 [start_date] 
   FROM [tbl_processdata_history]  where sdp_id=@sdp_id
   order by currentdata_id desc), @intime)) >= 5 ))                                            
    
   end

Comment: After that i have to insert the record to table.

Comment: @AkshayDod . . . Your trigger is not checking any such conditions.  If you have another question, then ask it as *another* question.  Your trigger is simply broken, because it assumes that `inserted` has only one row.  That is a false assumption.